# Creating lambda expressions on the fly

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def multipliers():
  l = []
  for i in range(4):
    l.append(lambda x : x * i )
  return l

>>> ll[0](2)
6
>>> ll[1](2)
6
>>> ll[2](2)
6
>>> ll[3](2)
6
```

Can you explain the result here? I was hoping to get:

```
0
2
4
6
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python  (see the second answer for how to deal with your problem, and the first to explain why it happens)

Comment: Although I don't blame you for not finding that: it took me like four tries with Google, despite the fact I knew that question existed.

Comment: `site:stackoverflow.com python lambda` turns up several good results (including that one).

Comment: As pointed out in the thread, a simple way to solve this issue is to use `i` as a default argument for the lambda: `lambda x, i=i: x*i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, as people say, `i` is not a local variable of the `lambda`.
You have to fix that: using a default parameter value changing during the loop:

```
>>> def multipliers():
  l = []
  for i in range(4):
    l.append(lambda x, i=i : x * i )
  return l

>>> lst = multipliers()
>>> lst[0](2)
0
>>> lst[1](2)
2
>>> lst[2](2)
4
>>> lst[3](2)
6
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is that Python’s closures are [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding). This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function is called. So as a result, when any of the functions returned by `multipliers()` are called, the value of `i` is looked up in the surrounding scope at that time. By then, regardless of which of the returned functions is called, the for loop has completed and `i` is left with its final value of `3`. Therefore, every returned function multiplies the value it is passed by `3`, so since a value of `2` is passed in the above code, they all return a value of `6`

Taken from : http://www.toptal.com/python/interview-questions

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` is not stored inside the `lambda` function. That's why you're getting the result you're seeing: Python is using the value of `i` it finds when the function is called.